# Сортировки, реализация на dotNet

Tags: c#, .net, pascal, сортировка

Работаю с реализацией различных типов сортировок. Начал с самого простого.

Возникло несколько вопросов:

1. У меня в трёх сортировках (Bubble, Coctail, Gnome) всегда получается равное число обменов - так и должно быть, или у какой-то сортировки должно быть меньше/больше? В чём может быть ошибка, если разное число обменов?
2. На малых массивах данных QuickSort проигрывает по времени выполнения предыдущим трём сортировкам. Решается ли как-то эта проблема, или это нормально?
3. Для массива 50 000 чисел идут следующие результаты:

   - BubbleSort - 29,793 сек., 72.575.048 тактов
   - CoctailSort - 18,404 сек., 44.832.160 тактов
   - GnomeSort - 21,542 сек., 52.476.365 тактов
   - QuickSort - 0,043 сек., 105.991 тактов
     Не уверен, что так долго должно работать. Кто что думает?
4. Какие виды сортировок вы используете для различных типов данных и ситуаций для максимально высокой скорости обработки?
5. Как сильно зависит скорость выполнения сортировки от языка программирования, на котором написана программа? Какой язык, на ваш взгляд, показывает оптимальную скорость работы?
6. Хотелось бы это всё дело визуализировать и анимировать. В какую сторону копать? Мне бы хотя бы какой-то пример для старта, потом разберусь.

Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Не сваливайте вопросы в 1 кучу. Задавайте по 1 вопросу в вопросе.

Comment: @KromStern зачем дробить связанные между собой вопросы? Если только ради того, что бы кто-то рейтинга получил на простых вопросах - то это глупо.

Comment: Дело не в рейтинге, а в разделении тем, чтобы не мешать все в 1 кучу.  Не забывайте, SO это база вопросов и ответов, а не индивидуальных консультаций.

Comment: @KromStern понятно, но в данном случае разделение вопросов может не пойти на пользу читающим, т.к. не дадут общую картину. По крайней мере мне так кажется.

Comment: Здесь задано 6+ отдельных широких вопросов, какую общую картину они по вашему должны сформировать? ) SO предназначен для конкретных прикладных вопросов.

Answer (score 6):

Самая большая проблема вашего вопроса в том, что вы почему-то постеснялись показать свой код. Обсуждение кода без кода - вещь довольно бессмысленная. 
Поэтому вкратце:

1. Сразу на трех алгоритмах - маловероятно (если они у вас правильно реализованы). В случае с пузырьковой сортировкой и сортировкой "коктейльной" - да, вполне возможно
2. Как верно было замечено выше, на небольших объемах данных это нормально. Тут также стоит отметить, что быстрая сортировка может сильно просесть в производительности, если неудачно выбран опорный элемент. В этом случае может потребоваться "квадратичное" время
3. Скорее всего у вас неправильно реализована быстрая сортировка. Для нее это ненормальные показатели. Как именно - без кода не скажешь. Но если вы не желаете показать код, то можете найти в интернете множество примеров ее корректной реализации. Сравните с вашим вариантом.
4. Это типичный наивный вопрос новичка. В подавляющем большинстве случаев используют уже готовые механизмы сортировки, предоставляемые языком.Они давным-давно отлажены и достаточно хорошо написаны гораздо более квалифицированными людьми, чем пользователи этих алгоритмов. Свои велосипеды зачастую куда хуже и требуют времени на их написание, отладку и тестирование. Зачем тратить свое драгоценное время на то, что кто-то тысячу раз сделал до вас?
5. Зависит, конечно. Но сейчас никто не выбирает языки по такому признаку. Условно говоря, если вы хотите написать приложение под Android, то выбирать для этой цели Си, потому что "в нем сортировка пузырьком быстрее" - несколько странный вариант

Answer (score 1):

1) Сортировка пузырьком и шейкером, по идее, должны давать одинаковое количество перестановок, про третью не знаю.

2) Если quicksort - это сортировка хоара, то на очень маленьких массивах такое возможно, т.к. тут становятся заметны накладные расходы на рекурсивные вызовы, на больших размерах входных данных эти накладные расходы не видны за счет большей эффективности самого алгоритма. В стандартных библиотеках эта проблема вроде как решается выбором разных сортировок в зависимости от входных данных. Особенно надо иметь ввиду что если подать на вход quicksort уже отсортированные или почти отсортированные данные то время работы может значительно ухудшиться.

3) Да, такое возможно. Т.к. время работы quicksort растет значительно медленнее чем у Bubble, Coctail, Gnome в зависимости от размера входных данных ( `n*log(n)` против `n*n`, где n - размер входных данных)

4) В реальном мире используются библиотечные реализации сортировок.

5) Так же как и общее время выполнения программы. Компилируемые языки без сборки мусора в среднем показывают лучшие результаты чем другие языки. Но выбирать язык по скорости сортировки - не самая лучшая идея.

6) Это лучше отдельным вопросом, но такие вопросы не очень приветствуются т.к. на такой вопрос нельзя дать хороший ответ, так как вариантов очень много они обладают разными плюсами и минусами (вам в итоге видео надо или гифку, или вам на форме пользователю надо показывать, или еще что-то?).

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритмы сортировки оцениваются по скорости выполнения и эффективности использования памяти. При этом у каждого алгоритма есть модификации, которые позволяют сократить количество шагов или памяти.

1. Если вы посмотрите на характеристики алгоритмов Bubble, Coctail и Gnome, то увидите у них примерно одинаковые показатели сложности.

   Bubble: Худшее время O(n^2), Лучшее время O(n), O(1) вспомогательный

   Coctail: Худшее время O(n^2), Лучшее время O(n), O(1) вспомогательный

   Gnome: Худшее время O(n^2), Лучшее время O(n), O(1) вспомогательный

   Однако надо понимать, что при разных входящих данных у каждого могут получиться разные результаты. А могут получиться и равные результаты. Обычно ориентируется на худшее и лучшее время для алгоритма и реже на внутренние особенности.
2. Да, это нормально для QuickSort. Если посмотреть на графики, то можно увидеть, что чем больше входящих данных, тем лучше себя ведут сортировки O(log(n)) по сравнению с другими.

[image: O notation]

3. Я не знаю какие вы использовали входящие данные и реализации, это может сильно влиять на результат.
4. Встроенные в язык средства, зачем плодит велосипеды на практике?
5. В большинстве случаев играет роль скорость обращения к памяти, компилируемые языки в этом плане немного выигрывают, если использовать свои велосипеды. В случае с встроенными средствами не важно, оптимизация позволяет не задумываться об этом.
6. Все зависит от ваших знаний, в том числе GUI. Какой-нибудь Canvas и простая пауза могут вполне подойти.

Answer (score 1):

4. Об оптимальном алгоритме сортировки.
   Для массива из **N** элементов существует **N!** вариантов их старшинства, среди которых мы должны выбрать один. Для этого достаточно **log<sub>2</sub>N! ~ Nlog<sub>2</sub>N** операций сравнения.
   Так, для **N=5 N! = 120 < 2<sup>7</sup>**, т.е. достаточно **7** сравнений (алгоритм найдите самостоятельно).

Таким образом, оптимальный алгоритм должен иметь сложность **Nlog<sub>2</sub>N**. Этому условию удовлетворяют алгоритмы сортировки слиянием.

Для алгоритма быстрой сортировки также анонсирована оптимальная сложность, но в наихудших условиях он её не подтверждает.

Указанные рассуждения не относятся к вырожденным случаям (когда в силу дискретизации или иных причин в массиве много одинаковых элементов) - например, к массиву из нулей и единиц.

Answer (score 0):

1. Данные сортировки имеют одинаковую сложность О(n^2), а вот о конкретном количестве операций говорить некорректно, может совпадать, может не совпадать (тут будет слишком много факторов)
2. Это нормально, одно из улучшений QuickSort, как раз и связано с досортировкой малых массивов, например, вставками.
3. Вряд ли вам тут кто нибудь что то скажет. Профайлер в руки и проверять.
4. "Родные" для среды. Писать свои "велосипеды" вместо использования стандартных в большинстве случаев бесполезно или даже вредно.
5. Слишком холиварный вопрос.
6. А что вы уже знаете? Это и используйте.